# Apple Watch bluetooth Connection Lost

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, apple-watch

I have connected Apple Watch with my iPhone 6. Do we have any trigger method which can identify if connection is lost between Apple Watch and iPhone. I have tried with core bluetooth. But, not able to get any method when connection get lost.

Please let me know if you have any other idea..!!!

Comment: I think the only way to detect the connection lost with Apple Watch is to try to communicate with it every x seconds and check the result of WCSession. This mean to have an App that uses the bt frequently and can compromise the battery duration